# Why am I getting @types/node issue in VSC if I don't even know what is it?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue3 project and Volar is diplaying an issue:

> @types/node version incompatible. @types/node version 18.11.0 is incompatible to Vue version 3.2.41, it will cause DOM event type broken in template.

But my project doesn't event have such package included.
My package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
  "firebase": "^9.12.1",
  "i18n": "^0.15.1",
  "pinia": "^2.0.23",
  "vue": "^3.1.0",
  "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
  "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.0",
  "eslint": "^8.25.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
  "prettier": "^2.7.1",
  "sass": "^1.26.5",
  "vite": "^3.1.0"
}
```

I can't also find anything of similar name in node_modules. Where is that issue coming from?

Comment: This is an error or a warning? You probably have some packages not working well together. What package manager are you using here?

Comment: @types/node is going to be a dependency of one of your dependencies.  if you search your lock file you'll probably find it.  try manually adding @types/node `18.8.0` to your devDependencies which is a current workaround solution from the linked github issue found [here](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/2003)

Comment: It's an issue displayed by Preview Doctor, not the console. I'm using NPM. The issue comes from Volar.

Comment: I can't find this dependency in package-lock either. Or in node_modules folder. Tried adding manually different versions of @types/node. Didn't help.